# Why does web3py transtactions not work in my code?

Tags: python, transactions, blockchain, web3py

```
from web3 import Web3 
import requests

*i have also connect to a node provider before this function.

def buy_coin_token():
    from_acc = str(input("Sender acc:"))
    private_key = str(input("Senders private key:"))
    to_acc = str(input("Receiver acc/contract address:"))
    amount_to_send = input("Amount to send:")
    gas = int(input("Gas:"))
    gas_price = int(input("Gas price:"))
    nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(from_acc)
    tx = {
        'nonce': nonce,
        'to': to_acc,
        'value': amount_to_send,
        'gas': gas,
        'gasPrice': gas_price
    }
    signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, private_key)
    tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    print("Your transactions has is "+(tx_hash))
```

I am trying to make a transaction on the bsc and i keep bumping into the same error:

> TypeError: Transaction had invalid fields: {'value': '0.005'}

I have turning it into and int, float, and str, and I also though of doing the toWei function but I am afraid that it wont work and that it will send more that its supposed to.

I also want to test it into a bsc test network

Comment: Using a float should work.  Show us the code that uses a float, and the new error message.

Comment: the error stays the same:TypeError: Transaction had invalid fields: {'value': 0.005}

Comment: is there a possibility it may be because i have to define the value as ether?and if i do how much bnb will it transact?

Comment: If you tried float and int, then i don't know what else it could want...

Comment: tried that already,same error

Comment: So it says `Transaction had invalid fields: {'value': 1}` ?

Comment: Does the error happen on the `signTransaction()` call, or the `sendRawTransaction()` call?

Comment: it happens in the sign transaction call ,because the value information in tx is wrong

Comment: it says :Transaction had invalid fields: {'value': 0.005}

Comment: it says 0.005 because i want to send 0.005 bnb

Comment: You said you tried integer.  What was the error message then?

Comment: when i use an int it gives me this error:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.005'

Comment: That error is not from the API; that is Python telling you that the string `"0.005"` cannot be converted to an integer.

Comment: I believe the API requires an integer in that field.  If you're trying to send `0.005`,  you have misunderstood how to use the API.